# Disable VSCode file icons

Tags: finder, icon, visual-studio-code

After installing VSCode, it's decided to make every program file use an icon with the VSCode logo on it. Is there anyway to disable it? It's annoying since it removes the quick preview feature that I use a lot.

Below is an example of what I mean:

[image: An example]

I'd like to get rid of that VSCode icon entirely, without having to set a custom icon by hand. I'd like to just cancel what VSCode does.

Comment: By quick preview, do you mean [Quick Look](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/view-and-edit-files-with-quick-look-mh14119/12.0/mac/12.0) which lets the user take a look at the contents of a file by pressing the Space bar when on the file without opening it in the Finder?

Comment: I believe that during installation of VS Code you also decided/agreed to make it a default application to open text (based) files.

Comment: > By quick preview, do you mean Quick Look ... 


Yes, I love that feature so much when I'm just browsing.

Comment: >  I believe that during installation of VS Code you also decided/agreed to make it a default application to open text (based) files. 

I don't recall ever agreeing to that (I wouldn't intentionally have done it), but my question isn't necessarily VSCode specific, I would just like to override the file icon settings an app has set for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the Spacebar Preview behavior?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439961/how-to-change-the-spacebar-preview-behavior)

Comment: Yes, that answers my question, thanks!